# Calculating integrals by Weddle's rule

Tags: python

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this formula?

```
def Weddle1(f, a, b, n): 
h = (b - a) / n
summa1 = 0
summa1 += ((3*h/10)*(f(a)+5*f(a+h)+f(a+2*h)+6*f(a+3*h)+f(a+4*h)+5*f(a+5*h)+f (a+6*h)))
return summa1
```

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: What are you trying to do? :)

Comment: i am trying to calculate integral by Weddle's rule

Comment: What specific problem or error do you have with your code? How are you using it? What output do you expect? What output are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on line 4, you have something like `f(a)` but the problem is that f is not a function, so if you are trying to multiply, you should do `f*(a)`, and also, it's not indented correctly.

Comment: What makes you think that f is not a function?

Comment: Welp, because Weddle's formula takes in 4 numbers, none of which are a function.

Comment: Since we don't know how the OP is calling `Weddle1`, it is not unlikely that `f` is supposed to be the function they are trying to integrate.